# How to use Webstorm to Git

Tags: git

I can use Webstorm to Git previous , but it can't work now ,Ican't push at all. I set Git for many ways . Now I am crazying. I don't know which setting is right . I set :

```
    git config --global http.proxy
```

When I clone repository :

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxxx/xxxx.git': 
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8087: Connection refused
```

or

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxxx/xxxx.git' :
Failed to connect to github.com port 1080: Time out
```

How can I use Webstorm to Git?

Answer (score 0):

In order to initiate a new git repository you can simply navigate to your project folder using `git bash` and run `git init`; it will set it up for you. From that point, you can manage your `git` repository whichever way you like.

If you insist on using **WebStorm** tools you can follow steps as it is outlined on the website

1. Open the project you want to store in a repository.
2. On the main menu, choose VCS | Import into Version Control | Create Git Repository.
3. In the dialog that opens, specify the directory where you want to create a new Git repository.
4. Put the required files under Git version control. The files appear in the Version Control tool window under the Default node.

**Reference**

[Version Control with WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/version-control-with-webstorm.html)
[Setting up a Local Git Repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/setting-up-a-local-git-repository.html)